# SQL LITE add column with count of occurencese

Tags: sqlite

I'm using sqllite and I have a table as the following example:

```
ID state 
1   init
2   run
3   stop
4   run
5   init
6   stop
7   run
```

I'd like to add a column which count the occurrence of "run" state only if the "init" state is encountered, for example:

```
ID state session
1   init   0
2   run    1   <---first occurence
3   stop   1
4   run    1
5   init   1 
6   stop   1
7   run    2   <---second occurrence
```

Is there a way to do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because of I'm using QT to manage SQL database I solved in this way

```
QSqlQuery query;
bool initFlag = false;
int countSession = 0;

if (query.exex("SELECT id, state FROM table"))
 { 
 while (query.next())
 {
   if (query.value(1).toString() == "init")
    initFlag = true;
   if (initFlag && query.value(1).toString() == "run")
   {
      countSession++;
      initFlag = false;
   }

   QSqlQuery update;
   update.exec("UPDATE table SET session = "+QString::number(countSession)+" WHERE id = "+query.value(0).toInt());
 } 
}
```

Comment: Without ORDER BY, SELECT does not guarantee any sorting.